# why (-1)^n is not monotonic sequece

Tags: sequences-and-series

I believe I have a very easy question that makes me confused but I need to clear my mind with your help.

A sequence is called monotonic increasing if $a_{n+1}>a_n$ and monotonic decreasing if $a_{n+1}<a_n$ using this definition I got a sequence mon. decreasing when $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$. However when I applied this little definition to $(-1)^n$ sequence as a result I got $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(-1)^n}=-1$ and since $(-1)<1$ it suppose to be a monotonic decreasing but which is not true since $(-1)^n=(-1,1,-1,1,...)$ is a not monotonic.

So where am I making mistake any help will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Try writing down the first few terms of the sequence. Can you see a pattern?

Comment: A sequence is called monotonic increasing if a_n+1>a_n and monotonic decreasing if a_n+1<a_n using this definition I got a sequence mon. decreasing when a_n+1/a_n<1. However when I applied this little definition to (-1)^n sequence as a result I got (-1)^n+1/(-1)^n=-1 and since (-1)<1 it suppose to be a monotonic decreasing but which is not true since (-1)^n=(-1,1,-1,1,...) is a not a monotonic. So where am I making mistake any help will be great.

Comment: How can you get $a_{n+1}/a_n<1$ from $a_{n+1}<a_n$?

Comment: The criterion you use only works for sequences of positive terms.

Comment: The given definition *implies* the quotient property. It is not an *if and only if* condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of "monotonic decreasing" applied to a sequence $a_n$ means specifically that $a_{n+1} < a_n$ for every $n.$

This is *not* the same as $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1.$
In particular, if $a_n < 0$ and $a_{n+1} < a_n,$
then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} > 1.$
That is, when you divide by a negative number, you reverse the sign of the inequality.

If you replace one test of a definition with another 
(in this case, testing $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ instead of $a_{n+1} < a_n$)
and this causes different things to fit the definition, 
it is a sign that your change to the test was inappropriate,
not that there is any ambiguity about the original definition.